# Hardness of constrained star system problem?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness

A star system is a family $F$ of n subsets of n-elements set $S$. A star system is graphical if there is some graph $G(V,E)$ such that $F$ is the family of vertex neighborhoods in $G$. It is $NP$-complete to decide whether a given star system is graphical.

> What is the minimum occurrence of each element such that the problem remains $NP$-complete?

**EDIT 12-12-2010**: I added another question:

> What is the most restricted class of graphs for which the problem remains $NP$-complete?

For instance, Is the star system problem $NP$-complete if the target graph is cubic? If not, What is the minimum $k$ such that the problem remains $NP$-complete for $k$-regular target graphs?

[F.Lalonde, Le probleme d'etoiles pour graphes est NP-complet, Discrete Math.
33(3), 1981, 271-280.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X%2881%2990271-5)

Comment: can you give a reference for the $NP$-completeness of this problem, or (even better) a short argument for it?

Comment: @Williams, it is equivalent to the problem of deciding whether a bipartite graph has an automorphism of order 2 interchanging the two color classes.

Comment: As a side note: if you require the witness graph $G$ to exclude a path/cycle on at most four vertices, then the problem is polynomial time - http://www.springerlink.com/content/05g8151w58700g66/

Comment: The correct link for Lalonde's paper is http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(81)90271-5

Answer (score 3):

You may take a look at [The Star System Problem revived](http://www.ii.uib.no/~telle/bib/FKT.pdf). Among other things, the authors prove that:

> if the graph $G$ is required to be $C_k$-free, i.e. not allowed to have an induced cycle of length $k$, then the problem is solvable in polynomial time for each $k \le 4$, and is NP-complete for each $k>5$.

In addition, you may find the papers in [this list](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=8154835037185315057&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=2000&hl=en) useful.

Comment: Thanks Sadeq, I'm aware of those references and I did not find an answer to my question.